# Converting $\frac{d\, y}{d\, x} = x^2 + y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ to variable separable form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is as follows:

> Use method of separation of variables to solve 
>   $$\frac{d\, y}{d\, x} = x^2 + y^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

I am aware of following two methods (as given [here](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/2233/2233-l11.pdf)) for converting differential equations to variable separable form:

- If $\frac{d\, y}{d\, x} = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$
- If $\frac{d\, y}{d\, x} = F(ax + by + c)$

But I don't know how to use this knowledge to convert given differential equation to variable separable form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, the equation is equivalent to $$y^{-2/3}y' = y^{-2/3} x^2 + 1 = \frac{x^2}{(y^{1/3})^2} + 1.$$ [I say this only holds formally because to verify that it holds rigorously, we would need to prove that $y \neq 0$ for any $x$.] Making the substitution $u = y^{1/3}$ we see $u' = \frac{1}{3} y^{-2/3} y'$ so inserting $u$ into the above equation we have $$3u' = \frac{x^2}{u^2} + 1 \implies u' = F\left( \tfrac u x \right)$$ where $F(z) = \frac 1 3 \left(\frac 1 {z^2} + 1\right).$ Now the equation is in the form you specified so you can solve for $u$ and then $y = u^3$.